# how to use grep in R to select the correct id from a query

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to use `grep` in R to select the correct id from a huge list of id's. It works for most of them but not for others. For example when i use this

```
> grep("cp_gi_88656873.2", names(data), value = T)
[1] "cp_gi_88656873.2"  "cp_gi_88656873.29"
```

it is giving me two id's rather than one. To make this more stringent i am adding a `$` to the end of the query and it works ok

```
> grep("cp_gi_88656873.2$", names(data), value = T)
[1] "cp_gi_88656873.2"
```

Is there other ways around to solve this problem without adding `$` to the end of id's? I ask this i have several hundred id's and i have to add `$` to each one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `\\b` at the beginning and end of the pattern.

```
grep('\\bcp_gi_88656873.2\\b', v1, value=TRUE)
#[1] "cp_gi_88656873.2"
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c("cp_gi_88656873.2", "cp_gi_88656873.29")
```

Comment: I assume `\\b` is for word border. Right? Anyway thanks

Comment: @upendra Yes, it is.  You mentioned that it is hard to paste `$` at the end.  `?paste` could be of use here. or `grep('^cp_gi_88656873.2$', v1, value=TRUE)` a modification of your solution in case there are other prefixes.

Comment: how to make this work? currently not working. `gene <- "cp_gi_88656873.2"` `grep('\\bgene\\b', names(data), value = T)`

Comment: Try `paste` i.e. `grep(paste0('\\b', gene, '\\b'), v1, value=TRUE)#
[1] "cp_gi_88656873.2"`